# Haskell back tracking recursion

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, maze

I am implementing this in haskell.

https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/

I able to reach the get the list when the "goal" is reached but if the goal is not accessible, the list is not updated. For example

```
...#@                           !!!#@
..#..                           !!#..
.##.#     it should return      !##.#
...#.                           !!!#.
```

My code as follows

```
path maze x y
    | x >= length (head maze) = (False, maze)
    | y >= length maze = (False, maze)
    | x < 0 = (False, maze)
    | y < 0 = (False,maze)
    | check maze x y '+' = (False, maze)
    | check maze x y '#' = (False,maze)
    | check maze x y '!' = (False, maze)
    | check maze x y 'G' = (True,maze)
    | fst east = (True,snd east)
    | fst south = (True, snd south)
    | fst west = (True, snd west)
    | fst north = (True, snd north)
    | fst noWay = (True, snd noWay)
    | otherwise = (False, maze)
            where 
                    noWay = path (changeVal maze x y '!') x (y+1)
                    north = path(changeVal maze x y '+') x (y-1)
                    south = path (changeVal maze x y '+') x (y+1)
                    east = path (changeVal maze x y '+') (x+1) y
                    west = path (changeVal maze x y '+') (x-1) y
```

I am not getting the result. I am new in Haskell, can anyone give me a boost so that i could solve this silly problem.

Comment: the `NoWay`/`!` part was added by you right? There are two things that might go wrong with it: first you *go down* with `noWay` but you already did that and saw that this is impossible with `south` - so this case should never be matched and I don't think you will never mark something with "!". Why don't you mark it in the `otherwise` case at the end (remove the `noWay` case) - that should do the trick. I would happily check this if you post the complete code (with example) somewhere ;)

Comment: This is the whole code. changeVal changes the value at a coordinate and check checks the value at a coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately, the cause of your problem seems to be that

```
| otherwise = (False, maze)
```

uses the original `maze` instead of returning an updated one.  However, even replacing it by `snd noWay` won't give you the output you want. (I think it will only mark with `!`s the part southward from your starting point.)

There is a greater problem:  When continuing to the next recursive step, your function is not keeping the marks placed by the previous step, but instead starting from the original `maze` again. Instead, the next recursive step needs to start with the final maze markings produced by the previous one. E.g. (seeing as your guards go east -> south -> west -> north) you need `south` to leave off where `east` finished, with something like

```
south = path (snd east) x (y+1)
```

If you fix up all your directions similarly, then you don't need `noWay`.  (There will be no unmarked places left to check by that point.)  Instead if the `north` case fails, then it will have marked everything except your initial point, so you can do

```
| otherwise = (False, changeVal (snd north) x y '!')
```